Use IntellitraceSC for monitoring a not already started service
I've an Azure Pipeline where I'm building a solution and running some unit/integration tests.
The tests are executed using the vstest.console.exe application.
What I'd like is trying to use IntelliTraceSC to collect important event from the tests and have a possibility to debug them in case a test is flaky and fails.
I know that one possibility would be to use the launch command of the IntelliTrace tool and pass the vstest.console.exe with its parameters as parameter itself.
But I cannot do that. What I'd like to do instead is start a collector that will be attached the vstest.console.exe when it will start, run the tests and close the collector.
Then fetch and save the .iTrace file that can be used for investigation.
Is it possibile to instruct IntelliTrace to attach to a specific process by passing its name? Thanks
